# Facebook login button

Tags: facebook, fbml

Using Facebook's FBML login button, is it possible to use custom login/logout images?

```
<fb:login-button 
    autologoutlink="true" 
    onlogin="OnRequestPermission();">
</fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head over to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810335/how-to-change-facebook-login-button-with-my-custom-image/9811496#9811496), I have already explained this and also provided the code. Let me know if it still needs further clarification.

Sachin!

Source : [How to change facebook login button with my custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810335/how-to-change-facebook-login-button-with-my-custom-image/9811496#9811496)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible, using the JavaScript version:

```
<a href="#" id='fb-connect-link' onclick="FB.Facebook.init(api_key, channel_path);FB.Connect.requireSession();return false;">
            <img src="/media/default/img/button_facebook.png" alt="F" /><br />Facebook<br />(via Connect)</a>
```

I used this before and it works.

Comment: :) if it hasn't changed in the meantime that is, facebook has some strange policies about changing it's api's

Answer (score 3):

Nealv's answer demonstrates old API. If you want to use new API then you need to call [`FB.login()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login) method to trigger fb login dialog at any point.

Answer (score 1):

Nope that's not possible, Facebook does not allow that because of its branded icon/image.

If however, you are using JavaScript for that, see the answer of @Nealv.