# Stylize facebook button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating web application with facebook login. And i have a problem with stylizing login button. The default facebook login button is inside iframe and my css styles doesn't aply to this element. I tried also to use jquery `.click()` function to trigger hidden button but it doesn't work too.

this is default facebook button:
[image: default facebook loginn button]
and this is the final effect what I want to achieve:
[image]
this button is already in my html, it looks great but it doesn't work because default button must be clicked. My question are:
1)Is there any way to stylize facebook login button?
2)How to trigger working `click` event on facebook button using jquery?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe). Hope it'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to you **first question**:

Of course, you can stylize the Login Button. One way of doing it is my using a custom image and writing your own Javascript to mimic the functionality.

Have a look at this related question "[How to change facebook login button with my custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810335/how-to-change-facebook-login-button-with-my-custom-image)" for more details.