# Changing a facebook login button to a custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have search for this answer and have received different ideas, however none of them seem to work. It is likely that I am not attaching the onclick function to the correct element, so I just want to see where I am going wrong.

I will use this modal window as an example of what my code looks like:

```
<div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">
    <header class="popupHeader">
        <span class="header_title">Login</span>
        <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    </header>

    <section class="popupBody">
        <! -- Here Goes all the Login and signup Forms -->
        <!-- Social Login -->
        <div class="social_login">
            <div class="">
                <a href="#" class="social_box fb">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>    </span>
                    <span class="icon_title">Connect with Facebook</span>

                </a>

                <a href="#" class="social_box google">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>    </span>
                    <span class="icon_title">Connect with Google</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="centeredText">
                <span>Or use your Email address</span>
            </div>

            <div class="action_btns">
                <div class="one_half"><a href="#" id="login_form" class="btn">Login</a></div>
                <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" id="register_form" class="btn">Sign up</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Username & Password Login form -->
        <div class="user_login">
            <form>
                <label>Email / Username</label>
                <input type="text" />
                <br />

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" />
                <br />

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="remember" type="checkbox" />
                    <label for="remember">Remember me on this computer</label>
                </div>

                <div class="action_btns">
                    <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                    <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Login</a></div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <a href="#" class="forgot_password">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Register Form -->
        <div class="user_register">
            <form>
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" />
                <br />

                <label>Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" />
                <br />

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" />
                <br />

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="send_updates" type="checkbox" />
                    <label for="send_updates">Send me occasional email updates</label>
                </div>

                <div class="action_btns">
                    <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                    <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Register</a></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<script>
(function($) {
    $(".fa fa-facebook").on("click", function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                _wdfb_notifyAndRedirect();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I am also not against using the facebook code, however for some reason their codes do not seem to work on my page either.

The script codes to run the modal window works fine however if I add any other script to the page, they don't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to change "Connect with Facebook" button right ?

Comment: Ideally the connect with facebook icon would actually connect with facebook. If it is easier to use the FB code rather than an onclock, then id happily change, however I am not so sure why this code isnt running.

Comment: Try using this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9811496/4763053 this might help you