# How to replace facebook button with custom image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using facebook javascript login sdk for a normal app. I have written a script for this. But i want to replace facebook login button with one of my custom image.

Comment: Here is a fiddle for my script https://jsfiddle.net/2k052fwz/

Comment: your fiddle doesn't do squat

Comment: It is showimg fb login image on my local but not on fiddle.

Comment: so, there must be a lot more wrong in your code than you think

Comment: Follow the simple step
[Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810335/how-to-change-facebook-login-button-with-my-custom-image)

Comment: check out my answer. for the future: please include all the neccessary details in your question (what have you tried so far? what is your code? where exactly did you get stuck? ...).

Comment: @luschn: i just want to replace exisiting fblogin image with any of custome image. I added html and javascript code but it is not showing image on fiddle but showing on local.

Comment: we know that ;) - you should edit your question and add information instead of putting it in comments. always be as detailed as possible in your questions. anyway, check out my answer. that is how it works. you can style your button any way you want.

Comment: have a look on this url http://www.theumang.com/fblogin/   i want to remove this image

Comment: again, check out my answer if you want to use your own image. everything´s there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own login button by using [`FB.login`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.5) of the JavaScript SDK.

HTML:

```
<button id="loginBtn">Facebook Login</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //do the login
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
}, false);
```

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/