# MVC Facebook Login Button Style

Tags: css

I have this code to create a Facebook Login Button in MVC:

```
<fb:login-button style="height:200px;" scope="public_profile,email,user_friends,user_about_me,user_likes" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

It all works fine but I see the button with this style:

[FBActualLogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrMvK.png)

I want to see the button like this:

[Facebook Login ButtonStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFQ6T.jpg)

And I also want to change background color in the hover

How can I do it with CSS?

Comment: Changing the background color on hover is just applying a :hover pseudo class. Example `.button:hover { background-color: red; }`

Comment: Hi Bon!Thanks for your reply.I know how to use css..i don't know how to modify an fb:login-button object to trasform it in my second image.

Comment: Looks like styling this button is not possible as it is creating an iframe behind the scenes. What you can do is create a button using html / css (not the facebook button) that will look like the one in your requirement. Then on click, call the facebook api to show the login page.You may refer to this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810335/how-to-change-facebook-login-button-with-my-custom-image)

Comment: Thanks it works fine. You are a great!